# Check list item in listbox with database list items

Tags: php, mysql

I need help in this and am very confusing thinking how to do this.

I have a form, an update/edit form, inside it I have a multiple selected listbox.

In my database records:

```
ID Items
1  Apple
2  Banana
3  Orange
4  Pear
5  Starfruit
```

And whenever the user clicks on edit which brings them to this form where I have made the listbox highlighted according to their previous saved data.

When the user clicks update, the listbox in the update form will look like this:

```
<option selected>Apple</option> <-- highlighted
<option>Banana</option>
<option selected>Orange</option> <-- highlighted
<option>Pear</option>
<option selected>Starfruit</option> <-- highlighted
```

This is what the user will see according to their 1st chosen items which was saved previously.

Currently I'm doing hard coding it:

```
<?php
$select=mysql_query("select * from products_list where id='$id' "); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){

$product_category = explode("\n", $row['category']);
$i=0;

    echo '<select name="product_category[]" id="category" size="9" multiple="multiple"><option value="Black" ';
if ($product_category[$i] == "Black" ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; $i++; }
echo '>Black</option><option value="White" ';
if ($product_category[$i] == "White" ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; $i++; }
echo '>Black</option><option value="Blue" ';
if ($product_category[$i] == "Blue" ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; $i++; }
echo '>Black</option>';
}
?>
```

And so on so forth. I only list a few. So I would like to ask is there a way that I can do this, if my listbox options are not hard coded?

Hope you guys understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry if i misunderstood you and your code but I think this is what you want to do:

```
<?php
$select=mysql_query("select * from products_list where id='$id' ");

// Insert the categories in an array in order
$categories = array('Black', 'White', 'Blue', ...);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
    $product_category = explode("\n", $row['category']);

    echo '<select name="product_category[]" id="category" size="9" multiple="multiple">';

    foreach($product_category as $i=>$value)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$categories[$i].'"';

        if($value == $categories[$i])
        {
            echo ' selected="selected"';
        }

        echo '>'.$categories[$i].'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: Hi Summoner, for the categories array, must is be hard coded? Can I pull the arrays from another database that has already has a set of options?

Comment: Sure you can. Just loop over the rows in the database and push the categories in the array. I don't know your database structure and how the fields relate so I can't be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, because I'm quite confuse with your codes. =x

Let's say I have 2 database

Database_1 (all the available options)

ID Items
1  White
2  Black
3  Blue

Database_2 (user options that is stored in database)

Items
White
Black

Is this clear enough?

Comment: Do I need to use the JOIN mysql select statement for this to be done?